# Content not rendered on webpage, React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to render the h1 tag when following the path '/', however, when I refresh the page the text doesn't show up. I have already switched the  tags with  tags as I was following an old tutorial. I am using react-router-dom v6.

HomePage.Js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import RoomJoinPage from "./RoomJoinPage";
import CreateRoomPage from "./CreateRoomPage";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Link, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

export default class HomePage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/'>
            <h1>This is the home page</h1>
          </Route>
          <Route path='/join' element={ <RoomJoinPage /> } />
          <Route path='/create' element={ <CreateRoomPage/> } />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

App.Js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import HomePage from "./HomePage";

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <HomePage />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const appDiv = document.getElementById("app");
render(<App />, appDiv);
```

Comment: Welcome Omar. Do you mean the h1 tag (not the p tag)?

Comment: yes the h1 tag.

Answer (score -1):

**set your routing in app.js like this**

```
<Router>
   <Switch>
      <Route exact path='/'>
            <h1>This is the home page</h1>
      </Route>
      <Route exact  path='/join'> </Route>
      <Route exact path='/create'> </Route>  
   </Switch>
</Router
```

> 

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I am using react-router-dom v6 so the switch tags don't exist.

Comment: include exact on your  route